# how to be stretch the last div which always at right postion

Tags: html, css

i have the problem with the making layout my program i just want 3 div fixed at the left side and another div at right which is flexible (fluid).

here is the code which is i used:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <style>
  div{
  display:inline-block;
  padding:20px;
  border:1px solid blue
  }

.fluid{

}
</style>
 <body>
  <div style="width:100%">
   <div>123456</div>
   <div>prahsant</div>
   <div>123456</div>
   <div class="fluid">123456</div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: it will not occupy the remaining width

Comment: Yes? http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I think you're looking for `float`, not `display:inline-block`.

Comment: Why do you want to use `div`s and not create a `table`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/v2k84/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/prashantbirajdar123/3DAVS/

Comment: @ElliotM what i read is div performance is better than table.may be i wrong. i am new to this.

Comment: @ElliotM Have you ever tried to make a table with 4 columns, of which only the last column stretches to fill the remaining space? besides, this doesn't look like it should be in a table.

Comment: @prashantbirajdar At this point you shouldn't be concerned about performance. Make it work first, then worry about efficiency. Premature optimisation is the root of all evil!

Comment: @MrLister okay. your suggestion is accepted.

Comment: @MrLister Not to enable an argument, but http://jsfiddle.net/fenderistic/TcxM5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="side">
        <div class="sec">123456</div>
        <div class="sec">prahsant</div>
        <div class="sec">123456</div>
        <div class="clr"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="fluid">123456</div>
    <div class="clr"></div>
</div>

<style>
.clr{clear:both}

    .main{
        min-width:400px; /* 100px reserving for the fluid div*/
    }
    .side{
        background:#CCC;
        float:left;
        width:300px;
    }
    .side .sec{
        float:left;
        width:100px
    }
    .fluid{
        background:#F00
    }</style>
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/ashishanexpert/B8L6L/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this? I am not using floats.

**HTML**

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="side">
        <div>123456</div>
        <div>prahsant</div>
        <div>123456</div>
    </div>
    <div class="fluid">123456</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    display:inline-block;
    padding:20px;
    border:1px solid blue
}
div.main {
    display: block;
    position: relative
}
div.side {
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0;
    top: 20px;
    border: none;
}
div.fluid {
    display: block;
    margin-left: 290px;
}
```

**[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v2k84/2/)**

**--EDIT--**

Removed `width: 100%;` as overflow occurs when padding is also set.

This method will work for most widths but you may need to set some media queries when the window is re-sized to a small width.

Comment: div.fluid {
    display: block;
    margin-left: 290px;
} here you fixed the left size...it may be vary..run time the layout will change..any one of fix div may be hide..then it won't work